# Android: set all view to visible for testing/ debugging purposes

Tags: android, xml, layout, view

I was wondering wheather when previewing the layout in Android Studio I can see all view regardless of their visibility in order to inspect all the elements in the preview without changing something in the code (just for debugging purposes).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use:

```
android:visibility="gone"
tools:visibility="visible"
```

the `tools` namespace is there for this type of situation where it's only relevant for development.

and then just import:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

in your root layout, if your IDE doesn't suggest it